# Determining length of gap of binary number

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I am trying to do the following exercise (found on Codility):

[image]

The way I have approached it is by using pointers. E.g. the binary representation of 25 is 11001. We start off with i = 0, j = 1, and a variable gLength = 0 that keeps track of the length of the gap.

If the i'th index is 1, check for the j'th index. If the j'th index is 0, increment gLength. If the j'th index is 1, check if gLength is greater than 0. If it is, then we need to store this length in an `ArrayList` as we have reached the end of the gap. Increment i and j, and repeat.

Here's the method in code:

```
public static int solution(int N) {
    String binaryStr = Integer.toBinaryString(N);
    // pointers
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    // length of gap
    int gLength = 0;

    while (j < binaryStr.length() && i < j) {
        if (binaryStr.charAt(i) == 1) {
            if (binaryStr.charAt(j) == 0) {
                gLength++; // increment length of gap 
            } else if (binaryStr.charAt(j) == 1) {
                // if the digit at the j'th position is the end of a gap, add the gap size to list. 
                if (gLength > 0)
                    gapLengths.add(gLength);
                i++; // increment i pointer
            }
        } else {
            i++; // increment i pointer
        }
        j++; // increment j pointer
    }

    Collections.sort(gapLengths);
    // Line 45 (ERROR)
    int maxGap = gapLengths.get(gapLengths.size() - 1);
    return maxGap;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:400)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
at Codility.solution(Codility.java:45)
at Codility.main(Codility.java:15)
```

I've marked down where line 45 is in the comments. After further investigating (with the debugger), I found out that I get the error because no length(s) seems to be getting added to the `ArrayList`. Does anybody know why?

I hope this was clear, if not please let me know. I'm not sure if this method would execute in O(log n) time like required, but for now I just want to have something working - then I will think about the time complexity aspect of it.

Big thanks for any help.

Comment: `binaryStr.charAt(i) == 1` probably doesn't do what you intend...

Comment: Note: you don't need to put all of your gaps into a list; you only need to keep track of the largest one.

Comment: I wonder if converting to a string violates the space complexity requirement. It takes O(log N) space to convert a number to a binary string; however, since N is strictly bounded to 2^31-1, one could argue that the space is bounded by a constant. (It can be done without converting to a string, using shifts)

Comment: Good advice, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `if (binaryStr.charAt(i) == 1)`. You are comparing `char` with `int`.

**Replace:**

```
if (binaryStr.charAt(i) == 1)
```

and

```
if (binaryStr.charAt(j) == 0)
```

**With:**

```
if (binaryStr.charAt(i) == '1')
```

and

```
if (binaryStr.charAt(j) == '0')
```

**Edit:** (As pointed out by [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner))

Before doing `int maxGap = gapLengths.get(gapLengths.size() - 1);`, you need to check `if gapLengths.size() > 0` to make sure you have atleast 1 element in the the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be annoying, I think the guys have offered great help for your algorithm. I propose, well, I believe it is an easier approach to use

```
String[] result = binaryStr.split("1");
```

And then go about just checking the biggest element of the array.

Edit: apparently I missed the part regarding the big O restriction, so I worked a different algorithm:
If you take a look at this page http://www.convertbinary.com/numbers.php
you'll notice that the gap starts at 5 (0 gap) then 9 (00 gap) then 17 (000 gap) etc..(in increasing order), the quick relation I noticed is if you start at 5 then add (5-1=4 to it) you'll get the 00 gap at 9, then 9+8 = 17 (000 gap) etc..

I believe you might be able to come up with a certain fixed calculation to get the best performance out of this without having to do String or Char work.

Comment: That's a nice way of doing it, never thought of that. Out of curiosity can you achieve a running time of O(log n) using this technique?

Comment: Just edited my answer, maybe now it will give you an advantage in terms of performance restrictions, hope this helps

Comment: The binaryStr which having trailing_zeroes are not covered by this.

eg : n=6 =110_2
✘WRONG ANSWER 
got 1 expected 0

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution in Swift:

```
let number = 5101
let binrygap = String(num, radix:2).componentsSeparatedByString("1").map { (a) -> Int in
a.characters.count}.maxElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution 100%

```
public int solution(final int N) {

//Convert number to Binary string
String bin = Integer.toString(N, 2);

System.out.println("binary equivalent = " + bin);
int gap = 0;
int maxGap = 0;


for (int i = 1; i < bin.length(); i++) {

  if (bin.charAt(i) == '0') {
    gap++;
  }
  else if (bin.charAt(i) == '1') {

    if (gap > maxGap) {
      maxGap = gap;
    }
    gap = 0;
  }

  }
 return maxGap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 implementation.

`

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int N) {
        while(N%2 == 0){
            N /= 2;
        }
        String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(N);
        String[] matches = binaryString.split("1");
        Optional maxValueOptional = Arrays.stream(matches).max(String::compareTo);
        return maxValueOptional.isPresent()? ((String) maxValueOptional.get()).length():0;
    }
}
```

`